# Is there anyway to combine a static geojson and data from database then display it in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, export, database

I do have a web map application that can load geojson then display it on leaflet map, however  I encountered unresponsive script whenever I refresh my page due to big size of geojson. Is there anyway that I do have this static geojson of province then link it to data from database?

I am just a newbie.

Comment: There may be ways to improve your map's performance without using a separate database (and depending on your needs, using a database may not improve performance without other changes). It is useful to first identify ways you might decrease the size of your GeoJSON. Is it big because it contains a lot of detailed geometry or because there are lots of properties for each feature? Both? If you have lots of geometry, can you simplify it? If you have lots of properties, are you going to need them all in your map?

Answer (score 1):

Clustering can help. See https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster

Here a 50000 marker example http://sintef-9012.github.io/PruneCluster/examples/realworld.50000.html